# Similar Java Library like Jpedal

Tags: library, java

Please recommend some other libraries or solutions like jpedal library, I use it for printing pdf from java but Jpedal is not open source and they only allow for 14 days trial, being a student I cannot purchase jpedal for my projects

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Thank You so much I will keep this thing time for next time. I am editing the question.